# Script is not working in IE Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using click event function to save the every activity of the user in the database, but the script is not working in IE browser. Please suggest me to fix this issue.

```
  document.addEventListener("click", function(event){     
  var url_path = window.location.pathname;   
  var type = event.target.type  
  var name = event.target.name  
  var old_value = event.target.value  

  if(name === undefined || name == null || name.length <= 0)  
   {

   }  
  else  
  {

   $.ajax({type: "POST",
   url: "application/record_user_activity",
   data: { click_obj_type:type, click_obj_name:name,click_obj_old_value: old_value},
  success:function(result){
  // alert("success")
 }});

 }
});
```

Comment: Does anything work on IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for IE, use `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener` because `addEventListener` is not supported in IE < 9.

Also note that From IE > 11, `attachEvent` is not supported

Reference [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx)

So, try to use

```
if(window.addEventListener){
   //code
}
else if(window.attachEvent){
   // code
}
```

Comment: `addEventListener` is supported since IE 9: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener